# How to update foreign key column(Page Item) using Javascript on a page in Oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-18.2

I have a page to store and upload files in the database, which works fine,

Since this is a part of an application, I have a Foreign key column in my File Upload table which I need to update with the Primary key Item which is on another page. I know I have to set the Foreign Key Column using JavaScript, but I'm unable to update the column with the Foreign key.

I tried to set the Column Page Item using JavaScript:

```
$s('ForeignKeyPageItem','#PR_ID#');
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that when you move into the uploading page, set the value of ForeignKeyPageItem with the information you need.

otherwise, if the PR_ID is saved in the session state, you can use plsql dynamic action to preform:

```
apex_util.set_session_state('ForeignKeyPageItem', :PXX_PR_ID);
```